# Unable to display data in Product details using Realtime firebase, NextJs & antd

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, next.js, antd

Am unable to display Single product details on a [uid].js page, I have tried using different methods but couldn't find a solution.

I have provided both codes for Product Page and the Single product details page. Please help me to point out what am doing wrong.

Product Page - On this page products list is displaying fine without any problems.

```
product.js
.. 
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { app, database } from '../firebase/clientApp';
import { EyeOutlined, DeleteOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Table, Space } from 'antd';

import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const db = getDatabase();

const Products = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();

  const columns = [
   
    {
      title: 'name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
      key: 'name',
    },
    {
      title: 'Actions',
      align: 'left',
      width: 100,
      render: (item) => (
        <>
          <button onClick={(e) => seeMore(item.uid, e)}>View</button>
        </>
      )
    }
  ];
  //Getting all data

  useEffect(() => {
    const productsFunc= async () => {
      const productsData = ref(db, 'products/');
      onValue(productsData, (snapshot) => {
        let response = Object.values(snapshot.val())
        setProducts(response)
        setLoading(false);
        // console.log(typeof(response))
        console.log(response);
      });
    };
    productsFunc()
      .catch(console.error);

  }, [])

  const seeMore = (uid, e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    router.push(`products/${uid}`)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="site-layout-background" style={{ padding: 24, minHeight: 650 }} >
        <Space
          style={{
            marginBottom: 15,
          }}
        >
        </Space>
        <Table
          dataSource={products}
          columns={columns}
          bordered
          loading={loading}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
export default Products;
```

How ever am unable to use the UID to get the name from Product page above.

```
[uid].js

import { getDatabase, ref, onValue, get, child } from "firebase/database";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { app, database } from '../../firebase/clientApp';
import { useHistory, useParams, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const db = getDatabase();

const productDetails= () => {

  const [currentProduct, setcurrentProduct] = useState({})

  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = onValue(
      ref(getDatabase(), `products/${id}`), (snapshot) => {
        const prods= snapshot.val();
        setcurrentProduct(prods); // Data not reaching here
      },
      {
        onlyOnce: true,
      }
    );

    return unsub();

  }, [id]);

  if (currentProduct === null) {
        return <div>Loading the Product details...</div>;
    }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="site-layout-background" style={{ padding: 24, minHeight: 650 }} >
        <Space
          style={{
            marginBottom: 15,
          }}
        >
        </Space>
        <h1> Name -  {currentProduct.name}</h1>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
export default productDetails;
```

Comment: I see that you have `useRouter` imported, did you have a problem using it?

Comment: No, I didn't have any problem using it.

Comment: so why you're not using it? you do know you can get the query of the dynamic route using useRouter, I don't know if useParams will work here

Comment: I tried using `const { id } = useRouter()` but still not working. @mocherfaoui

Comment: I think you're not using `useRouter` quite correctly, you should first do `const router = useRouter()` and then `const {uid} = router.query`